# Swift header file is created with duplicate property

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm using a Swift class in Objective-C using the 'ProjectName-Swift.h' file which is automatically created. Unfortunately, every time I compile, I get an error in this file:

```
// Generated by Swift version 1.0 (swift-600.0.34.4.8)

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#include <objc/NSObject.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

....
....

@interface UISoundBar : UIView
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger barNumber;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor * barColor;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat barHeight;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat barSpacing;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray * bars;
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)showBars;
- (void)setupBars;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray * bars.storage;
@end
```

I left out some of the other generated code (...) The error is on the last line containing

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray * bars.storage
```

stating that 'property has previous declaration' and 'missing ;'. Once I delete this line everything works fine. It's just a nuisance to have to delete this every time I compile the project. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the original swift class that generates the above:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class UISoundBar : UIView {

  var barNumber = 4
  var barColor: UIColor = UIColor.redColor()
  @lazy var barHeight:CGFloat = {
     return (self.frame.height - CGFloat(self.barNumber) * self.barSpacing) /  CGFloat(self.barNumber)
  }()
  var barSpacing:CGFloat = 0.4
  @lazy var bars:UIView[] = {
    var tempArr:UIView[] = []
    for i in 1...self.barNumber {
      var v = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(i - 1) * (self.barHeight + self.barSpacing), self.frame.size.width * 0.1, self.barHeight))
      tempArr.append(v)
    }
    return tempArr
  }()

  init(frame: CGRect) 
  {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }

  func showBars()
  {
    for bar in self.bars{
      self.addSubview(bar)
    }
  }

  func setupBars()
  {
    for bar in self.bars {
      bar.backgroundColor = self.barColor
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `UISoundBar` is defined as a Swift class. Can you show the "original" Swift property definitions of that class?

Comment: ok, added the swift source

Comment: This seems to be a problem with using `@lazy` in an Objective-C class. A similar issue just came up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483652/lazy-init-to-variables-in-an-objc-class-in-swift.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish with declaring a property with dot syntax? Property declarations won't let you do that, and since `bars` is already declared, that's why it's telling you that you're trying to re-declare it.

Comment: As you can see, this file is automatically created at compile time.

Comment: My apologies, I scrolled too much and didn't see the initial line saying "Generated by Swift...". As @Martin-R said, could you show the "original" Swift property definitions? That could help us to see why it is generating the way it is. Could also be a bug, in which case you may want to file a radar.