# Lazy init to variables in an @objc class in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to use lazy initialization for instance for an Array in a class in Swift.
When i am using @objc declaration for the class, in order to use it in objective-c i got a compilation error. When i just use the class without @objc, i can compile it without any issues.

I get errors for this:

```
@objc class MyClass {
    @lazy var arr : String[] = String[]()
}
```

[image: Error generated]

For the following code, i get no errors:

```
class MyClass {
    @lazy var arr : String[] = String[]()
}
```

Thank you your help!

Comment: Both versions compile without errors for me. Tried restarting/updating Xcode?

Comment: this looks like a bug in the bridge code generator. `arr.stroage` in an internal field used for lazy property, which shouldn't expose to ObjC code like that.

Comment: In fact it clearly is an error in Objective C.  You can't have property names with dots in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case I think its a bug in bridge code generator [Developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/996116#996116).

> If anything which is not objective-C compatible compiler won't
>   generate it's objective-C equivalent (it won't give Error), For
>   example if you have a Generics or tuple that are not supported in
>   objective-C compiler is not going to generate objective-C equivalent
>   for this also it won't give error.

In the second case you are not including **@objc** , From apple doc :

> A Swift class or protocol must be marked with the @objc attribute to
>   be accessible and usable in Objective-C. This attribute tells the
>   compiler that this piece of Swift code can be accessed from
>   Objective-C.If your Swift class is a descendant of an Objective-C class, the compiler automatically adds the @objc attribute for you.

Hence this class is not included(not accessible) , so its not giving error.

Comment: Is it documented as incompatible? It can easily be implemented as a regular Objective-C method, my guess is they haven't had time to do that correctly, but may do so in the future.

Comment: *"@lazy … is not Objective-C compatible* - Do you have any reference supporting this statement?